# PHP - assigning values from the database, html link in the table

Tags: php, mysql

I made a script that takes data from the database and writes it in a table. I wonder how the link can assign a value (for example, serial number to be loaded from the database) and use it on another web page. I tried with dynamic link but it did not work. I pray for a proposal on how to solve this problem...

This is part of the code:

```
$query = "SELECT `code` FROM `articles` WHERE `code` LIKE '$codeart'";
        $query_run = mysql_query($query);
        @$query_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query_run);
        @$query_result = mysql_result($query_run,0,`code`);
        if($query_num_rows != 0){
            $query = "SELECT `art`,`price`,`code`,`quantity` FROM `articles` WHERE `code`='$query_result'";
            $query_run = mysql_query($query);

        while(@$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)){

             echo '<table border="1px" ><tr>';  
             echo $code = '<td width="25%"><a href="processing.php">'.$row['code'].'</a></td>';             
             echo $art ='<td width="25%">'.$row["art"].'</td>';
             echo  $price ='<td width="25%">'. $row["price"].'</td>';
             echo $quantity = '<td width="25%">'.$row["quantity"].'</td>';


        }
        echo '</tr></table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<td width="25%"><a href="processing.php?code='.$row['code'].'">'.$row['code'].'</a></td>';
```

From processin.php ,we can access code like this`$code=$_REQUEST['code'];`

Comment: That's it
I tried something like that, but it did not work. I need to see where I was wrong.